# getting specific rows in Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, parse-platform, integer

I'm building an app that gets items with an `averageReview` of 5.

```
-(PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    NSInteger goodReview = 5;
    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query whereKey:@"averageReview" equalTo:goodReview];  
    return query;
}
```

Xcode gives me this warning:

```
**Implicit conversion of 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC**
```

In Parse core I have a column named "averageReview" and the type is "number".

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed it an int value which is not of an object type. Use NSNumber for number values with Parse. The `@5` below is shorthand for `[NSNumber numberWithInt:5]`

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
      NSNumber *goodReview = @5;
      PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
      [query whereKey:@"averageReview" equalTo:goodReview];

      return query;
}
```